# × TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

function Component(props, context, updater) {

> 236 |   this.props = props;
>     237 |   this.context = context;
>     238 |   this.refs = emptyObject;
>     239 |   // We initialize the default updater but the real one gets injected by the

name.js

```
| import React,{Component}from 'react';
  2 | 
> 3 | class Name extends Component(){
  4 |     render(){
  5 |         return(
  6 |             <div> hello world</div>`
```

Comment: `class Name extends Component {`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow charitha! It's difficult to understand what you're asking. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Pls format or represent the code and question well!

Answer (score 4):

You have some sort of typo there. Try to remove parenthesis after `Component`, like this:

```
class Name extends Component {
  // ...
}
```